# Adding new element to Array - Swift 3

Tags: core-data, swift3

I have a Tableviewcontroller ***BeamsNameVC*** with 2 variables: *Name* and *number*.
If for example, the number is 7, and if I click on any row in this View controller, it will segue to another TableViewcontroller ***SpansListVC*** and than it will show 7 rows: *S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6 & S7*.

I want to save these Data, so I created 2 swift files:

```
class StructureElement: NSObject, NSCoding {

var name = ""
var nbrSpans = ""
var spans = [LoadDetailsForEachSpan]()
```

and

```
class LoadDetailsForEachSpan: NSObject, NSCoding {

var i_SpanName = ""
var i_Spanlength = ""
var i_ConcentratedLoadForEachSpans = [ConcentratedLoadForEachSpan]()
```

I created a protocol with the following:

```
let spanNbr = Int(structureElement[newRowIndex].nbrSpans)
let newElementDetailSpan = LoadDetailsForEachSpan()
    for i in 0...spanNbr! {
        newElementDetailSpan.i_SpanName = "S" + " \(i)"
        structureElement[newRowIndex].spans.append(newElementDetailSpan)
    }
```

If i run the application, it will segue to *** SpansListVC*** but all values are the last ***i***.

### Example:

if name is ***Test 7*** and number of span is ***7***, I will be having inside ***[Spans] *** **7** values with the same name:

```
spans[0] = S 7  
spans[1] = S 7  
....
```

Any mistake with above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the hell that mutable data objects can be ;). You are creating a single `LoadDetailsForEachSpan` instance and add that same instance a number of times to the array, while setting the `i_SpanName` property of that *same instance* every time the loop is iterated. You probably want to pull the instance creation into the loop:

```
for i in 0...spanNbr! {
    let newElementDetailSpan = LoadDetailsForEachSpan()
    newElementDetailSpan.i_SpanName = "S" + " \(i)"
    structureElement[newRowIndex].spans.append(newElementDetailSpan)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @thm for your reply.

however, i find another solution as follow and it works:

```
    var spanDetailAndLoadItem: [SpanDetailsAndLoads] = []

    for var i in 1...nbr! {
        let item = SpanDetailsAndLoads(name: "S\(i) - S\(i + 1)")
        spanDetailAndLoadItem.append(item)
    }
    self.spans = spanDetailAndLoadItem
```

Comment: The actual solution is exactly what I said: pull the creation into the loop. Your answer is also mostly disconnected from your question: `SpanDetailsAndLoads` is not in there.
Neither is `init(name:)`, nor is `nbr`.

Comment: I modified the code in a way to have it works and to save it too. however I will put yours as the correct question.